# Glob is not working when directory name with special characters like square brackets "[ ]"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have issue while using glob function when path directory with square brackets.

```
// Example 1 - working
$path = 'temp'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'dir - name';
$files = glob($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.txt');
// List all files 
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
```

Above code is working but when directory name with square brackets like dir[name] or dir - [name] then its not working.

```
// Example 2 - not working
$path = 'temp'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'dir - [name]';
$files = glob($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.txt');
// result got empty if file on that directory 
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all of you.

I got exact solution for my query. below code is a working for me

```
$path = 'temp'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'dir - [name]';
$path = str_replace('[', '\[', $path);
$path = str_replace(']', '\]', $path);
$path = str_replace('\[', '[[]', $path);
$path = str_replace('\]', '[]]', $path);
$files = glob($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.txt');
// List files
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Because `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in _Windows_ is \ too. Example of `foo/bar/baz\[\]/qux.txt`. Others operating systems will treat it as `foo`, `bar`, `baz[]`, `qux.txt` but _Windows_ will treats it as `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `[`, `]`, `qux.txt`

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use:
`$path = str_replace(['[',']',"\f[","\f]"], ["\f[","\f]",'[[]','[]]'], $path);`

All in one line.

Answer (score 1):

`[foo]` has a special meaning, it represents a character class (regular expression syntax).

So to have `[` and `]` mean square brackets *literally*, you have to escape them – by preceding them with a backslash.

Comment: not working with backslash also  $path = 'temp'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'dir - [name]';
$path = str_replace('[', '\\[', $path);
$path = str_replace(']', '\\]', $path);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$path = 'temp'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'dir - [name]';
$from = array('[',']');
$to   = array('\[','\]');
$files =glob(str_replace($from,$to,$path . "\\*.txt"));
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This does not work. `\[` and `\]` is not accepted by glob, but as suggested above, `[[]` and `[]]` is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party I know, but based on previous answers, and after testing on both Linux/Mac and Windows, I came up with this utility function:

```php
function glob_escape($path){
  return preg_match('/\[.+]/', $path) ? str_replace(['[',']', '\[', '\]'], ['\[','\]', '[[]', '[]]'], $path) : $path;
}
```

For practical reasons, the function only attempts to escape characters when there are opening and closing `[brackets]` in the `$path`, with minimum one character in between. Single-brackets `some[folder` and brackets without a char between `some[]folder` don't need to be escaped.

Usage example:

```php
$path = 'some/dir[brackets]here/more[brackets]blah';
glob(glob_escape($path) . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT|GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Tested on Linux and Windows.