# php directory with square brackets doesn't work

Tags: php

I want to grab the jpg file. My directory is ../database/CWBRadar/CWB05Radar[Wufenshan]/.

The codes are below:

```
$files = glob("../database/CWBRadar/CWB05Radar\[Wufenshan\]/*.jpg");
var_dump($files);
```

I can't get anything when I call var_dump($files) that print array(0) {}.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glob is not working when directory name with special characters like square brackets "\[ \]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899214/glob-is-not-working-when-directory-name-with-special-characters-like-square-brac)

Comment: I has read the article a few hours ago, but still doesn't work...

Comment: you could always just change the directory name

Comment: I know I can change the directory name without [], but my customers request that need [] with their providing files...

Comment: could alias and use that

Comment: Thanks. It works when I remove the chair(). My original code is chair() form path before glob, but it doesn't work. After I remove it, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the article Eddie mentioned, try this please. It should work.

```
$files = glob("../database/CWBRadar/CWB05Radar[[]Wufenshan[]]/*.jpg");
var_dump($files);
```