# glob() returns empty array when accessing a specific folder

Tags: php, file, indexing, glob

Im using the following function to get the file list from specific folders:

```
$files = glob("/path/to/file/*");
```

Sadly, when using the following folder path, glob doesn't output anything:

```
$files = glob("/var/www/html/dl-meta/anime/[Erai-raws] Anime name - 01~12 [720p][Multiple Subtitle]/*");
```

...Even tho the path is 100% valid. When copying this path to my file explorer, it works just fine (if we remove the `*` at the end).

Why is that? What character do I need to escape? Is there any other characters I should escape so that type of bug doesn't happen in the future?

Cheers.

Comment: Any ideas? Im completely lost here..

Comment: Are you trying to get local computer files name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must mask the following characters ? * [  ] with \ if they are not supposed to have any special meaning for glob.

See special characters in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
$files = glob("/var/www/html/dl-meta/anime/\[Erai-raws\] Anime name - 01~12 \[720p\]\[Multiple Subtitle\]/*");
```

**Update:**

I did some tests and found that the backslash does not work on Windows. In Windows, the backslash is directory separator and therefore cannot be used as an escape character. With a few exceptions, this expression can be used as a escape function for Linux and Windows:

```
$path = preg_replace('~[\[?{]~','[$0]',$path);
$files = glob($path.'/*');
```

This does not work on Windows with {} if the GLOB_BRACE option is activated. GLOB_BRACE for glob () is not available on some Unix / Linux systems.

Comment: How can you escape them? I tried `quotemeta();` but it also escapes characters I dont want and vice versa.. @jspit

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899214/glob-is-not-working-when-directory-name-with-special-characters-like-square-brac